# how to delete child, sub child, child of sub child on deleting parent?

Tags: mysql, sql, coldfusion

i have one table where in I am adding content, i have several columns like

```
id parentid  title
1    0       home
2    1       about
3    2       our works
4    3       our contribution so on...
```

when i delete the content it simply deletes the parent its child letting the sub child and child of sub child orphan. here my query i using it for deleting. in case I delete the about it must delete the our works as well as our contribution.

```
   DELETE FROM content
          WHERE id = x
           OR parentid = x
```

can anyone help me how shall i have to delete the whole chain while deleting the parent ? Thanks.

Comment: add  ON DELETE CASCADE  foreign key constraint for the relationships then delete the parent

Comment: I am not using foreign key here. parent is the column of the same table.

Comment: add it. then delete that's the easiest way.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE content ADD CONSTRAINT content_fk FOREIGN KEY (parentid) REFERENCES content (parentid) ON DELETE CASCADE`. getting an error saying Error on rename errno:150

Comment: both should be innodb

Comment: yeah it is innodb storge engine.

Comment: @SamD - I want to know is it possible to do this in the table ? the parentid is not the foreign key though.

Comment: MySQL doesn't support recursive queries...

Comment: @Oyeme - wow that's sad, so there is no way to do that with MySQL it seems :(